# Google Sheets Javascript won't load in browser

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listMajors();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Admittedly, I'm relatively new at much of this.

But I'm trying to create a simple landing page that is connected to a Google Sheet.  I want to host it as a subdomain off of my main website.  However, I can't seem to get it to actually load the information.  It works fine when I run it locally, but something seems to be stopping it in the browser.

I've also tried to get their [own example code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) to run off of my website, but it has the same problem and error message.

The error I keep getting appears to be the following:

```
"Not a valid origin for the client."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
```

To see what it is doing, check out http://thomasconant.com/teamStats2.html

Does anyone recognize this error and can suggest what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Kinda hard to help when you've shown none of your code that you're actually using.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a requirement for questions asking for help with an error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The code has been added

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with the actual client id you got.

Answer (score 0):

- What does your page which generates this error look like? It's hard to say without the code.

If you're using the Google API Client in Javascript, and this is a console error, I'm thinking that you have not [added the correct origin](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#troubleshooting) to your Google Developer Console.

```
Error: origin_mismatch

This error will occur during the authorization flow if the host and port used to serve the web page doesn't match an allowed JavaScript origin on your Google Developers Console project. Make sure you completed the Step 1.e and that the URL in your browser matches.
```

(*If this is the correct answer, don't forget to mark it!*) :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It makes sense what you're saying, and I went into my Project in the Google API manager and added my domain as an 'Authorized JavaScript origins', but I still get the same error.  I'm sure I'm just missing some step, as your answer makes intuitive sense as to what is causing the problem